# How to make entry transparent background?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

How to make entry with transparent background like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Qxt.jpg
I tried any option with label and things like this but anything wont work.

Comment: I don't think tkinter supports what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in [wiki-tcl](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Transparent+Toplevel), showing how make a transparent toplevel.

I know that's TCL but shouldn't to be hard convert the code to Python if that's what you are looking for.

Saludos,